# New ajax calls not resetting the existing data in the JSP table

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, dom

Below is my ajax function which retrieves the data from servelt and shows it fine in the jps and the problem is every time a new ajax calls is submit the form just appends the data into the results received from previous calls, I need reset the current values stored in the table `OrderResultContainer` and then display it with new data.

I tried

```
document.getElementById("OrderResultContainer").reset = ();
```

but it's just reset the entire form data and not showing any data in the page.

```
function addData() {
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var loading = document.getElementById("loading");
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("OrderResultContainer").style.display = "none";
    xhttp.open("POST","Order",true);        
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('orderform'));
    xhttp.send(formData);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {            
        if ((xhttp.readyState == 4) && (xhttp.status == 200)) {                 
            var jsonorderdata = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            txt = "";
            for (x in jsonorderdata) {                  
                txt += "<tr><td>" + jsonorderdata[x].ordernumber+"</td>""</tr>";

             }                                  
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";              
            document.getElementById("ViewOrderResultContainer").innerHTML = document.getElementById("ViewOrderResultContainer").innerHTML + txt;                
            document.getElementById("divOrderResultContainer").style.display = "";             
        }
          };                
        }else 
        console.log('Ajax call is failed');
}
```

Can anyone help me on how to reset the data in the table `OrderResultContainer` alone after a new ajax response received from servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You append the received data to the previous with following code:

```
document.getElementById("ViewOrderResultContainer").innerHTML = document.getElementById("ViewOrderResultContainer").innerHTML + txt;
```

So if you change it like following you would have only new data:

```
document.getElementById("ViewOrderResultContainer").innerHTML = txt;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of hard to see without the corresponding html but this looks like the problem:

```
document.getElementById("ViewOrderResultContainer").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("ViewOrderResultContainer").innerHTML + txt;
```

Your taking the innerHtml from the ViewOrderResultContainer and append the value from txt. If you do that more than once than it will keep growing. If you want to replace the text than replace it with

```
document.getElementById("ViewOrderResultContainer").innerHTML = txt;
```

p.s. the given javascript is not valid

```
txt += "<tr><td>" + jsonorderdata[x].ordernumber+"</td>""</tr>";
```